# How do I set the default sort order in open file dialog to "Name"?

Tags: gtk

Somehow the default sort order in open dialogues has changed to be sorted by Modified. It's changed in all programs, not just a specific one.

This forces me to reach for the mouse and click the Name column every time I open a file (maybe I'm nitpicking but this gets annoying...).

How can I set the default sort order back to Name? Nautilus sorts by name by default when I browse into folders.

Answer (score 16):

Run `dconf-editor` (I assume that you've already installed [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package),
then navigate to **org**->**gtk**->**settings**->**file-chooser** and set value of key **sort-column** to **name**
or simple click on "Set to Default" button

[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems that should work but my sort-column is already set to 'name', and I hit set to default just to be sure. When I goto open a file it's still sorting by modified (I've tried several programs).

Comment: I have the opposite problem - it's sorted by name, and I'd like it to be sorted by modified. I tried changing "sort-column" to "modified", but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. This let me change sort order in gtk2 apps like Firefox to have directories first like the rest of the system uses.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but could you solve the problem? I am having the same issue and I can't solve it.

Comment: For the record I just had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.10 (GTK4), folders were not sorted first in my case, as it used to be. I tried installing dconf-editor and updated these keys to no avail. But then I noticed a "gtk4" key under "gtk", in there is "settings → file-chooser" too and changing these worked ! So it looks like there's two similar config trees now (probably the default one for GTK3 and the other for GTK4), make sure you update the right one :)

Answer (score 7):

If the above dconf-editor answer doesn't work for you, try the method described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323523/default-file-open-save-sort-by-modified/344872#344872). Edit `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`. Look for the section beginning with `[Filechooser Settings]` and change `SortColumn=modified` to `SortColumn=name`.