# Default file open/save sort by modified?

Tags: dialog

I'd like the file open/save dialogues to be sorted by default by Modified.

I read this answer: [set default sort order](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83552/how-do-i-set-the-default-sort-order-in-open-file-dialog-to-name) and it didn't help.

I went to: org->gtk->settings->file-chooser and I set the value of key sort-column to "modified", it still sorted by name, so I tried "size", and no luck there either. It still sorts by name.

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04. Thanks for any help/suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the file `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`. You should see something like this:

```
[Filechooser Settings]
LocationMode=filename-entry
ShowHidden=true
ExpandFolders=true
ShowSizeColumn=true
GeometryX=2064
GeometryY=1053
GeometryWidth=768
GeometryHeight=638
SortColumn=name
SortOrder=ascending
```

Change `SortColumn=name` to `SortColumn=modified`.

I found out about this file from [this launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/982742/comments/6), although there the author states that changing the setting there did not work for him. It does work for me, whereas making the change in dconf-editor does not. This also answers [How do I set the default sort order in open file dialog to “Name”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83552/how-do-i-set-the-default-sort-order-in-open-file-dialog-to-name), but I do not have sufficient reputation to answer it there.