# File chooser view settings

Tags: gnome, filemanager

In Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME 3.10, replaced every shred of nautilus with pcmanfm 1.2.3.  Searched through every config file, checked the issue tracker, nothing can seem to explain how I can force the file chooser / save as / open dialog to show files in a compact view (or any view other than the one-column detail listing).

Part of the problem is I just don't know what the underlying process is for this in general - nautilus somehow?  pcmanfm?  gnome-shell?  gdm?  X?!

---

Here is an example of the **compact view**
[image]

Comment: You have example of the compact view ?

Comment: @Serg post has been edited with screenshot.

Comment: what I have is `nautilus 3.14.2` and there is grid view and list view. Here's my example of [grid view](http://imgur.com/fPsB3H5). Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. When I press Ctrl + O in firefox it shows everything in the list. Didn't notice that before

Comment: no I know about grid view and even zoomed out all the way out it's the order of the files and how the icon is above the text.  I ditched nautilus for that exact reason - because they removed compact view from the options all together.  jerks.

Comment: @Serg yeah annoying right?

Comment: OK, from what I understand so far, this is not file manager thing. Applications use `gtk` filechooser dialog.  I've found [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/344872/295286) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/83584/295286) but there's no option for changing view of the files. I'll dig around but so far I'd say it's not quite possible.

Comment: Yup, [confirmed](http://askubuntu.com/a/548802/295286)

Comment: of course lol can you add that as the answer so I can accept real quick?  I'm betting I'll need to find this again later.  Thanks!

Comment: Hold on, I'll ask around in the ubuntu chat if anything can be done

Comment: posted answer, but as I said, there's more experienced users than me, so stay on the lookout - somebody might provide a possible solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As found in my quick research online, particularly from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/548802/295286) answer on another askubuntu.com question, the file chooser and save as dialogues are related to the graphical toolkit upon which an application is built, and in no way related to default file manager. Since most programs use `gtk` toolkit under Ubuntu, I see no possible way of altering those dialogues. There's possibility of switching to Qt-based desktops, but at least in my experience under `razorqt` that didn't do the trick. Therefore my answer to this question is altering file dialogues is impossible. There's other, more experienced users that me, hence perhaps there might be other answer, so my answer isn't conclusive

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/6647927/3701431

Comment: It's never occurred to me. +1

Comment: realated - [GtkFileChooser patched with Icon View](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3540n5/gtkfilechooser_patched_with_icon_view/).

Comment: And this was [reported as bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/803824).