# Save/open-Dialog, file order, directories first

Tags: xubuntu, file-sorting

The file-open/save dialog can be sorted alphabetically by clicking on the column header or by manipulating `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` as described in the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/83552/10068) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/323523/10068).

However, I'd like to have the subdirectories sorted on top, i.e. directories `a/ b/ c/` before files `a.txt b.png c.svg` and so on. Is there a way to do it?

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: "Sort folders before files" option in file manger preferences doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Ron:(abolut the edit) It's not Code, it's a path.

Comment: @Ron: No, that affects only the file manager.

Comment: See the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element): "The code element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be an XML element name, a file name, a computer program, or any other string that a computer would recognize". Also a [meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11697/402004). I had only good intentions ;)

Comment: @Ron: You're welcome. I wanted to emphasize the path strongly, so that a knowing user immediately sees, that I know about that.